# react-navigation 4.0 transitionConfig upgrade to 5.0 cardStyleInterpolator?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Transition animation, working in version 4.0, but not working in version 5.0

doc 5.0: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardstyleinterpolator

doc 4.0: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator-1.0/#stacknavigatorconfig

May I ask what I wrote wrong,

#### In version 4.0

```js
const forHorizontalLeft = sceneProps => {
  const {layout, position, scene} = sceneProps;

  const index = scene.index;
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];

  const width = layout.initWidth;
  const outputRange = 1 ? [width, 0, -width * 0.3] : [-width, 0, width * -0.3];

  const opacity = position.interpolate({
    inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index, index + 0.99, index + 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1, 1, 0.85, 0],
  });

  const translateY = 0;
  const translateX = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange,
  });

  return {
    opacity,
    transform: [{translateX}, {translateY}],
  };
};
```

#### In version 5.0

```js
screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          cardStyleInterpolator: ({
            closing,
            current,
            index,
            insets,
            inverted,
            next,
            layouts,
            swiping,
            current: {progress},
          }) => {
            const _index = index;
            const width = layouts.screen.width;

            const inputRange = [_index - 1, _index, _index + 1];
            const outputRange = 1
              ? [width, 0, -width * 0.3]
              : [-width, 0, width * -0.3];

            const translateY = 0;
            const translateX = progress.interpolate({
              inputRange,
              outputRange,
            });

            const opacity = progress.interpolate({
              inputRange: [
                _index - 1,
                _index - 0.99,
                _index,
                _index + 0.99,
                _index + 1,
              ],
              outputRange: [0, 1, 1, 0.85, 0],
            });

            return {
              cardStyle: {
                transform: [{translateX}, {translateY}],
                opacity,
              },
              overlayStyle: {
                transform: [{translateX}, {translateY}],
                opacity,
              },
            };
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all those extra `_index +`.

Follow the example in the docs for the `forFade` animation and change styles there to implement your custom animation instead of pasting same code as stack v1. They are completely different and same code won't work.

For horizontal animation, there's already a built-in `TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS` animation which you can use instead of reimplementing https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transitionpresets

For a tutorial on animations, see https://callstack.com/blog/custom-screen-transitions-in-react-navigation/